# Sending a GET Request to GitHub API asking for a list of commit messages in a Pull Request

Tags: python, api, github, flask, server

I want my Python Flask server to send a GET Request to the GitHub REST API V3, asking for all commits messages in a Pull Request, and perhaps receive it as a single payload.

Any suggestions on how I can approach this issue?

**Edit** (additional explanation): 
The only thing I have tried that was successful was displaying the actual number of commit messages in a pull request. To actually display a listing of all of them is complex. This variable here -->

```
x = jsonRequest["pull_request"]["commits"],
```

would display commit list from

/repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number/commits in the GitHub developer documentation.

If I could display not just the list of commits as a count, but also all the messages included in it, that would be nice.

Documentation found here: [developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#response-4](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#response-4)

Comment: Tried anything?

Comment: The only thing I have tried that was successful was displaying the actual number of commit messages in a pull request. To actually display a listing of all of them is complex.
This variable here --> x = jsonRequest["pull_request"]["commits"], would display commit list from /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number/commits. If I could display not just the list of commits as a count, but also all the messages included in it, that would be nice.

Documentation found here: https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#response-4

Comment: And have you tried anything that was unsuccessful, or did not quite work out as you hoped? I note that the commits you point to do include messages...

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, the x variable is your list of commits right? If so then it is a dictionary. Try treating this as a dictionary, locate the message attribute (in your documentation, that is...)-->

```
"message": "Fix all the bugs"
```

..and do a for loop, assuming that your pull request as more than one commit with different kind of messages. Something like this

```
for msg in x:
print(msg['commit']['message'])
```

I don't know about turning this into a single payload, but you can try exporting all the message into a JSON object. So replace the print message with

```
import json
for msg in x:
json_object = (msg['commit']['message'])
file = json.loads(json_object)
print(json.dumps(file, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Quick word of caution: my code may not work since I haven't tested it out. Take it as reference.